# Create new users in AWS Cognito without a temp password email

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm running into an issue where new Cognito users cannot use the forgot-password feature until they have already logged in with a password (which kind of defeats the purpose).

User creation is successful and calling forgot password in the console provides no errors, but users never receive a forgot password email if their account status is Enabled/FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD

````
        user_pool_id: $pool_id,
        username: user['email'],
        message_action: 'SUPPRESS',
        user_attributes: [
          {
            name: 'given_name',
            value: user['first_name']
          },
          {
            name: 'family_name',
            value: user['last_name']
          },
          {
            name: 'email',
            value: user['email']
          },
          {
            name: 'email_verified',
            value: 'true'
          }
        ]
      }
      cognito.admin_create_user(params)```
````

Answer (score 3):

To allow your users to reset password on a completely new account you need to set a "fake" password yourself. You could just generate anything random (but still strong) and then set it like this (yes, it's not Ruby, but action should be the same):

```sh
aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password --user-pool-id <value> --username <email-address> --password <value> --permanent
```

After that your users will be able to trigger the "forgot password" action.

Comment: Sure enough that seems to do the trick. Is that referenced anywhere in the Cognito documentation?

Comment: @ScottHillson Not sure about that. I just remember stumbling upon this issue some time ago.